# Issue with FB.ui Share - share_open_graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, single-page-application

I am implementing sharing feature on my website.

Since my website is SPA I have decided to use FB.ui with "share_open_graph" share method.

`FB.ui({
      method: 'share_open_graph',
      action_type: 'og.shares',
      action_properties: JSON.stringify({
        object : {
          'og:url': this.pageUrl,
          'og:title': this.article.title,
          'og:site_name': 'Dedicated To My Love - Gift Ideas',
          'og:description': this.article.description,
          'og:image': window.location.origin + '/' + this.article.detailImageUrl
        }
      })
    }, function(response){});`

The only problem with the above code is, I'm not getting the option to "share the content to the pages I manage".

If I use the "method: share" instead, I'm getting both the options "to share on my wall" as well as "in the pages I manage".

How to overcome this issue?

Comment: by using Fb.ui share instead, and adding the correct og tags to your shared urls. in a SPA, you can do server side rendering or use prerender.io, for example.

Comment: @luschn Can you provide an example or share link where I can find an example for using FB.ui share with og tags in URL? Do I have to manually construct the URL with og tags?

Comment: what? in url? that´s really not what i meant. og tags need to be placed in the html code. http://ogp.me/

Comment: Got it. That's the problem. I'm using Angular 5 application without Universal build. Although Angular is talking care of updating all the page meta tags along with og tags FB is not picking. Since its a fully developed website its causing to much trouble making the server-side rendering to work and I don't want to use prerender, worried about site getting clocked.

Comment: i know what the problem is, please read my first comment again. FB ignores JS, and angular produces the metatags with JS. there are 2 possible solutions in my first comment. if you don´t want to use either of them, you are pretty much out of luck.

Comment: true. I will go with prerender.io I don't have any other options.